# ExpandableListView with button inside childs

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm writing an ExpandableListActivity with a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter that queries a DB. I added a button inside very child, and now i'm having bad time getting info on the item from the list that its button is clicked. I think that my problem is that i don't well understand how to handle data within the adapter. Most of the examples are about listadapter like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627096/android-expandablelistviews-and-checkboxes).
My adapter got getChildView implementation and what i cannot achieve is to retrieve the _id of the clicked group from the original cursor. Because i didn't know how, i tried in the following code to get the name from the group textview but in every child that i click i get the name of the first item in the list.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);
        v.inflate(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.productsexpchilditem, null);

        Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        String name=((TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.txt_exp_products_name_item)).getText().toString();
        button.setTag(name); 

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ProductsActivityExp.this, "TOAST "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });      
        return v;
    }
```

BTY I didn't implemented the getGroupView method, cause when I did it I lost all the displayed text in the groups (but not in the child). I really think the work with cursorTreeAdapter got specific implementation different then listadapter.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't used ExpandableListView, but it seems strange that you get name value via parent. Its not surprising that you get same name for all buttons.
Can you explain in details, what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clearer: i'm taking from a DB table items - each row in the list is the name of the item and when you expand by clicking the row with the name, you can see more details about the item. Beside the details there is a button, and i want that click on it will make an operation on the specific item. Problem is that the button is inside the "child" and from there i cannot get the item properties to pass them along (specific: send with the button click the name of the item that isn't in the child but in the group that was expanded). Hope it's more clear.

Comment: Understand. Try set button tag to getGroupId(groupPosition) or value of other column via getGroup(groupPosition).get... .

Comment: The problem was that i didn't implement the CursorTreeAdapter interface as needed. I change from SimpleCursorTreeAdapter to regular CursorTreeAdapter and after the overriding of the "bind" methods for child and group, everything works like should be.